# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 400: "Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.openai.com/v1/completions" (migrating GPT-3 to GPT-3.5 API)

Tags: java, android, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have an android application where I'm currently using chat gpt 3.0 for completions and it works fine. Now after they released chat gpt 3.5 turbo, I made few changes based on their request example but throwing 400 errors, I appreciate any help Thank you

- My code with gpt 3.0  (it works fine)

```
  public static void getResponse(Context context, String URL, String Token, TextView mQuestionText, TextInputEditText queryEdt, TextView mResponseText, String query) throws JSONException {

        mQuestionText.setText(query);
        queryEdt.setText("");
        mResponseText.setText("Please wait..");

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("model", "text-davinci-003");
        jsonObject.put("prompt", query);
        jsonObject.put("temperature", 0);
        jsonObject.put("max_tokens", 100);
        jsonObject.put("top_p", 1);
        jsonObject.put("frequency_penalty", 0.0);
        jsonObject.put("presence_penalty", 0.0);


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest =  new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL ,jsonObject, response -> {
            try {
                String responseMsg = response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
                mResponseText.setText(responseMsg);

                // SHUT DOWN TEXT TO SPEECH IN CASE OF QUERY CHANGE
                if(textToSpeech != null){
                    textToSpeech.stop();
                    textToSpeech.shutdown();
                    textToSpeech  = null;
                }

                // SPEAK THE RESPONSE FETCHED FROM SERVER
                textToSpeech(context,responseMsg);
            }catch (Exception e){
                // error
                Log.d("TAG","Error is   " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("TAG","Error " + error.getMessage());
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                params.put("Authorization","Bearer " + Token);
                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

- Now switching to 3.5 turbo where I'm using gpt-3.5-turbo as model

```
 public static void getResponse(Context context, String URL, String Token, TextView mQuestionText, TextInputEditText queryEdt, TextView mResponseText, String query) throws JSONException {

        mQuestionText.setText(query);
        queryEdt.setText("");
        mResponseText.setText("Please wait..");

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        ArrayList<ChatModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new ChatModel("user",query));

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("model", "gpt-3.5-turbo");
        jsonObject.put("messages",arrayList);
        

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest =  new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL ,jsonObject, response -> {
            try {
                String responseMsg = response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
                mResponseText.setText(responseMsg);

                // SHUT DOWN TEXT TO SPEECH IN CASE OF QUERY CHANGE
                if(textToSpeech != null){
                    textToSpeech.stop();
                    textToSpeech.shutdown();
                    textToSpeech  = null;
                }

                // SPEAK THE RESPONSE FETCHED FROM SERVER
                textToSpeech(context,responseMsg);
            }catch (Exception e){
                // error
                Log.d("TAG","Error is   " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("TAG","Error " + error.getMessage());
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                params.put("Authorization","Bearer " + Token);
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

- Error when using chat gpt 3.5 turbo model  ( when i use chat gpt 3.0 it works )

```
  E/Volley: [1922] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for 
  https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

- Based on their documentation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model.

There are three main differences between the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) and the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API):

1. API endpoint

   - Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`
   - Chat Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`
2. The `prompt` parameter (Completions API) is replaced by the `messages` parameter (Chat Completions API)
3. Response access

   - Completions API: 
     `response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("text")`
   - Chat Completions API: `response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("message")`

**PROBLEM 1: You're using the wrong API endpoint**

Change this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

**PROBLEM 2: Make sure the JSON for the `messages` parameter is valid**

Like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();
JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

message.put("role", "user");
message.put("content", "What are your functionalities?");

messages.put(message);

jsonObject.put("messages", messages);
```

This code will create the following JSON object:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "What are your functionalities?"
    }
  ]
}
```

**PROBLEM 3: You're accessing the response incorrectly**

Change this...

```
response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("text")
```

...to this.

```
response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("message")
```

*Note: If you're still getting API error `400`, make sure you have set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Be careful, `application/json, UTF-8` won't work.*

Comment: Thank you Rok for your answer , i have actually used both and still throwing the same 400 error , i have both urls in my project and i tried with both , here is an image of the other link error : https://ibb.co/sQq0nwy

Comment: First, try to print the response as whole (not just the message content) to see if you get any response at all. Do you still get error 400?

Comment: It does throw an error when posting , so there is no returned values or response

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but I guess there's something wrong with the `JSONObject`. Make sure the `messages` parameter you send to the API endpoint looks like this: `"messages": [{"role": "xxxxx", "content": "xxxxx"}]`. Let me know if you solve the problem because I'm curious, what's the cause.